# How to make Low-Level caching collaborate with Association caching in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am currently working on a project with Rails 5. I want to boost the performance, so I decided to use Low-Level caching like the following:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile

  def cached_profile 
    Rails.cache.fetch(['Users', id, 'profile', updated_at.to_i]) do
      profile
    end
  end
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, touch: true
end
```

It works fine respectively. But now I want to make the two caches to collaborate. What I want is that the associated object doesn't need to be retrieved from the database once it is retrieved from the cache store(redis here).

```
irb> u = User.take
irb> u.cached_profile # fetch from the redis. Can I set the association caching in `cached_profile`?
irb> u.profile # fetch from the database
  Profile Load (1.4ms) SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
irb> u.profile # fetch from the association caching
```

`u.profile` shouldn't fetch from the database because of it's already retrived from the redis, how to achieve this?

**Update 1:**

I found that there's an instance variable `@association_cache` in the instance of `ActiveRecord::Base`, which stores cached associations and determines if an association should be retrieved from the database.

I think I could do something like `user.instance_variable_get(:@association_cache)['profile'] = cached_profile` to make it work. But the value in the `@association_cache` is an instance of `ActiveRecord::Associations::HasOneAssociation` and I don't know how to build the `user` to it currently.

Comment: I am wondering why calling 'super` inside `cached_profile` is working, is shouldn't it be `'profile` instead?

Comment: @XavierDelamotte Sorry, it's a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: why do you need to introduce cached_profile as you know that `profile` is already cached automatically by rails ?

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html -> Caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an instance variable @association_cache in the instance of ActiveRecord::Base, which stores cached associations and determines if an association should be retrieved from the database.

We can achieve it with `@association_cache` like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile

  def cached_profile
    cache = Rails.cache.fetch(['Users', id, 'profile', updated_at.to_i]) do
      profile
    end

    reflection = self.class.reflect_on_association(:profile)
    if association_instance_get(name).nil?
      association = reflection.association_class.new(self, reflection)
      association.target = cache
      association_instance_set(:profile, association)
    end

    cache
  end
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, touch: true
end
```

Now we can avoid to refetch data from the database if it has been retrieved from the cache store.

```
irb> u = User.take
irb> u.cached_profile # fetch the profile from the database and use the redis to cache it
  Profile Load (1.4ms) SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
irb> u.profile # use the cached version from the redis
irb> u.profile.reload # reload from the database
  Profile Load (1.4ms) SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

**UPDATE:**

I built a gem [cache_associations](https://github.com/FX-HAO/cache_associations) for this.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include CacheAssociations

  has_one :profile
  cache_association :profile
end
```

It's doing the same thing, but it's neat and much easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

You may override directly the `profile` method to apply your low level cache.

```
class User
  has_one :profile

  def profile 
    Rails.cache.fetch(['Users', id, 'profile', updated_at.to_i]) do
      super
    end
  end
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user, touch: true
end
```

But beware, as you may encounter some surprises. You should udpate the cache on the `profile=` setter as well for example.

Comment: I think the `@association_cache` is the right way I should go.